# Finding number of solutions to $\sin(x)=x/10$ using an algebraic method.

Tags: trigonometry, transcendental-equations

I am trying to find the number of solutions of the equation $\sin(x)={x/10}$. While I know about the graphical method of doing this, I want to know if there are any quicker and/or algebraic method to solve this.

Comment: No, there is no algebraic way to find the solutions.

Comment: If all you want is the number of solutions, and you don't care about the $x$-values, that's another question.

Comment: We can see that $x$ must be between $0$ and $10$.

Comment: Your title is asking abotu the *number* of solutions, while the body of the questoins says you want to find the solutions. Which is it? These are two very different tasks...

Comment: Strictly speaking, the graphical method does not guarantee that all real roots are actually found. Usually, it will however lead to the right solution.

Comment: @MathGeek You mean , we must have $-10\le x\le 10$ or equivalent $|x|\le 10$

Comment: @Peter Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: There are no closed-form solution except $x=0$. Other solutions can be expressed using user special functions. Numerical approximations of these solutions can be found by various methods https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake @5xum, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the range of $\sin(x)$ is restricted to $[-1, 1]$, we only need to consider values of $x$ in the range $[-10, 10]$ since $|x/10| > 1$ when $|x| > 10$. Also, since both $\sin(x)$ and $x/10$ are odd functions, the solutions to this equation are symmetric about the $y$-axis, meaning if $x_0$ is a solution, then so is $-x_0$.

For clarity, I'm going to define $f(x) = x/10.$

First, zero is the obvious solution.

Second, since $\sin(x)$ has a slope of $1$ while $f(x)$ has a slope of $1/10$ at  $x=0$, $\sin(x) > f(x)$ for small $x$. There must be a solution in the interval $[\pi/2, \pi]$ since $\sin(\pi/2) > f(\pi/2)$ and $\sin(\pi) < f(\pi)$.

From $x = \pi$ to $x = 2\pi$, there can be no solutions since $\sin(x)$ is negative here.

The function $\sin(x)$ is positive again from $x = 2\pi$ to $x = 3\pi.$ Since $3\pi < 10$, the $\sin$ function rises from $0$ to $1$ and falls from $1$ to $0$ in this interval, meaning $f(x)$ could intersect $\sin(x)$ once (tangentially) or twice. In our case, the answer is twice:

1. Once in the range $[2\pi, 5\pi/2]$ since $\sin(2\pi) < f(2\pi)$ and $\sin(5\pi/2) > f(5\pi/2)$.
2. Once in the range $[5\pi/2, 3\pi]$ since $\sin(5\pi/2) > f(5\pi/2)$ and $\sin(3\pi) < f(3\pi)$.

Each of the three positive solutions has a corresponding negative solution, so the total number of solutions is $7$.

Comment: I think we can be satisfied that an interection in $ \ (2\pi \ , \ 3\pi) \ $ will not be tangential, since it would have to occur where $$ \ (\sin x)'|_{x \ = \ c} \ = \ \frac{1}{10} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \sin c \ = \ \sqrt{1 \ - \ 0.1^2} \ \approx \ 0.995 \ \ . $$  But this would correspond for the linear function to $ \ x \ =  \ c \ \approx \ 9.95 \ > \ 3\pi \ \ , \ $ where $ \ \sin x \ $ is already negative. So this line and the sine curve do not intersect in that way.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer was made before the edit of the question**

Consider that you look for the non trivial zeros of function
$$f(x)=\sin(x)-\frac x {10}$$
The first derivative cancels  close to $(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$  but you need to look at those which are $\in(-10,10)$.

Around these points, perform series expansions
$$f(x)=\left((-1)^n-\frac{(2 n+1)}{20} \pi  \right)-\frac{1}{10} \left(x-\pi 
   \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{2} (-1)^n \left(x-\pi 
   \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\pi 
   \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^4\right)$$  Solve the quadratic (keep the closest solution) to get an estimate of the solution.

For example, looking at the first non-trivial positive root
$$x_{(1)}=\frac{1}{40} \left(4+60 \pi -\sqrt{3216+480 \pi }\right)=3.09411$$ while the solution, given by Newton method, is $x_{(1)}=2.85234$.

For the second non-trivial positive root
$$x_{(2)}=\frac{1}{40} \left(-4-\sqrt{3216-800 \pi }+100 \pi \right)=7.09126$$
while the solution, given by Newton method, is $x_{(2)}=7.06817$.

If you want more accuracy, just use one or two iterations of Newton method. For example, the first root is poorly approximated but, using this estimate, look at Newton iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & x_k \\
 0 & 3.0941114 \\
 1 & 2.8557329 \\
 2 & 2.8523434 \\
 3 & 2.8523419
\end{array}
\right)$$